# Shadow stack implementation on x86_64

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, control-flow

In [Control Flow Integrity](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/control-flow-integrity/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fpubs%2F64250%2Fccs05.pdf), a protected shadow stack is implemented using x86 segments via LDT. But in x86_64 segmentation is disabled. Is there any other mechanism available which can be used to implement a protected stack on x86_64?

**Edit**

Found a recent [paper](http://www.cs.ucy.ac.cy/~eliasathan/papers/eurosys17.pdf) which describes several alternatives.

Comment: Technically speaking in long mode there are still segments. FS and GS still are usable. You can set a base for these segments but you can't set a limit (on most processors)

Comment: But I believe it would not provide memory isolation since it can be accessed with DS as well.

Comment: I wasn't saying you could use it for this purpose, was just pointing out that segmentation isn't entirely gone even in long mode.

Comment: Right. Point taken. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the idea for 32-bit CFI is to set a limit on DS/ES/SS, and put the shadow stack *outside* that, so it can only be corrupted by instructions with a `gs:` segment override prefix.

This only works in compat mode (32-bit user-space) on x86-64, because CS/DS/ES/SS have fixed base=0 and no limit when the CPU is in long mode.

FS and GS can have a non-zero base even in long mode, but even if you could set a limit on those segments, it's the opposite of what you need.  (That would protect regular memory from instructions with a `gs` prefix, instead of the other way around.)  Fun fact: [@MichaelPetch says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420204/shadow-stack-implementation-on-x86-64#comment85841819_49420204) most CPUs don't support a limit on those segments in long mode anyway.

---

**For the [Linux x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI)** (32-bit pointers in long mode), you could put the shadow stack outside the low 4GiB of virtual address space.  Normal compiler-generated code always takes care to truncate pointers to 32-bit.  The current default code-gen strategy (`-maddress-mode=short`) is to use address-size prefixes on every instruction with a memory operand, except `rsp`, which is assumed to always be zero-extended.

This leads to [a lot of wasted address-size prefixes](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85038), but it means that code compiled for x32 by current gcc will definitely truncate pointers to 32-bit, even when there's UB, making it impossible for compiler-generated code to load/store outside the low 4GiB of address space.

---

I don't think long mode has any general way to make a region of virtual address space accessible only with some kind of special instruction, either a prefix or something else.  So if you're defending against normal code using 64-bit operand-size, there are no options that replace segment tricks with baseline x86-64.  You'd have to map / unmap the shadow stack, which would be unusably slow.

There are several other technologies for enforcing / checking control flow these days.  [Intel's CET](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/4d/2a/control-flow-enforcement-technology-preview.pdf) (Control-flow Enforcement Technology) gives hardware support for various stuff, including a shadow stack.  [Grsecurity published a review / critique of it](https://grsecurity.net/effectiveness_of_intel_cet_against_code_reuse_attacks.php).  Their conclusion starts with "*In summary, Intel's CET is mainly a hardware implementation of Microsoft's weak CFI implementation with the addition of a shadow stack*."  IDK if this review is accurate.  Grsecurity does produce a competing product (which they acknowledge), so there might be some bias.  I'm sure CET is better than nothing.

See also https://github.com/huku-/research/wiki/Intel-CPU-security-features for a list of x86 (or maybe specifically Intel) CPU features that assist security in general (like MPX bounds checking), not just control-flow.